# Function-Based Index on numeric Column

Tags: mysql, indexing, sql-tuning

I have a table containing some numeric columns, and i have to keep them numeric because most of the time i will benefit from that. But i need also to make a generic search on those columns using partial matches so in my where statement i will have something like

```
...where num_col1 like "1234%...
```

My question is:

Can i make a function based index on num_col1 casting the column to CHAR? I tried but it seems it is not possible.

If no, do you guys have any other suggestions on how can i speed up the results of my queries?

I read around that some possible solutions could be either to create a View of my original table and there change the column type to varchar and index that column or another solution could be to add an extra varchar column to my table and index that. I would like to avoid both of these solutions because i have a really big table containing already a huge amount of rows and huge amount of columns.

Thanks in advance to everybody, 
Best, N.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your instinct to use the view is correct, to keep from duplicating the data.  But what are the needs that are optimized by numbers in one case and a string search in another?  Depending on those, it might make sense to take a look at the numbering system to see if you could search on a number range ( x >= 12340 and x < 12350 ) which would be much faster than a string compare.

Comment: The view is not fisible because i'm updating and inserting a lot of data in the original table really often. And searching in a range either because lets say that i have a column containing 12345678 i want this column to be in my query result if a user search for "1234".

Comment: I would do this to increase the speed then.. first, pull back the max ID to see what the size is in digits.  Then have the SQL generation object/script generate a WHERE that searches each range up to the max number of digits.  So if your max ID is 999999, and the user enters "1234", the WHERE clause generated would be:  "WHERE (id >= 1234 AND id < 1235) OR (id >= 12340 AND id < 12350) OR (id >= 123400 AND id < 123500)".  It'll take a little logic, but if a view is unfeasible and performance is important, it'll be easy on the DB.

Comment: @robert - not a bad way - looks a little bloated but probably solves the problem.  The actual requirement for what is being searched is still unclear.  is it always the beginning 4 digits?  note 'intelligent' keys are always an issue - so i would suggest go back to the original table design and maybe split that out in the first place.

Comment: @randy agreed.. i'm operating under the assumption that the table is already in heavy use and redesign is therefore costly, but if redesign is an option then splitting is the best case.

Comment: mmm i got your point robert but it will be not a good idea. My table has millions of rows and the numeric type is bigint unsigned. Lets say a user input only 2 digits in his search then there will too many OR in the where statements but i can give it a try. To answer Randy let me try to explain you better. You have a table with a lot of numeric columns and you want to give to the user the possibility of doing a global search in all of them. He can write 1 digits or more, as he prefers.

Comment: Give it a try.. even with a long string of dynamically generated "OR"s, my guess is it will still end up far faster than a string compare over millions of strings.  It's possible YMMV depending on your DB setup, though.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL doesn't have function based indexes, virtual columns or indexed views (afaik).

Quoting the note [on function based indexes in MySQL](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/functions?db_type=mysql) from my [SQL Indexing Tutorial](http://use-the-index-luke.com/):

> The backup solution is to create a real column in the table that holds the result of the expression. The column must be maintained by a trigger or by the application layer—whatever is more appropriate. The new column can be indexed like any other, SQL statements must query the new column (without the expression).

However, in your particular case, there is probably the risk that you will filter by an anywhere LIKE expression '%1234%'. In that case, b-tree will not help (explained in [LIKE performance tuning/indexing](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/searching-for-ranges/like-performance-tuning?db_type=mysql)). That would require full-text indexing, which works with MyISAM only.

Comment: i read that quotation, what i wanted to avoid is adding columns that basically just replicates the original ones, they just have a different types. So it would make more sense to create a mirror table with only text columns. Answering to the last part of your post no, i won't face the situation '%1234%'. I will have only '1234%' so index will work in those cases :)

Comment: @Kaiser Function based indexes is the feature you need. It still duplicates the data, but in the index only. MySQL doesn't have them, so you need to go for the backup solution (assuming that you cannot use ad DB that supports function based indexing ;). The backup solution will duplicate that data in the table AND in the index. And you have the strangeness that you need to query different columns in the WHERE clause. It's the generic backup solution...

Comment: That's exactly what i didn't want to hear haha :) I will probably go for the backup solution then ;) Thanks Markus.